# Filtering XML nodelist with Ajax and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, nodelist

I'm trying to build a page with AJAX and JavaScript that displays the contents of an XML file filtering it by node value.
The XML is similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

After the XMLHttpRequest, the CD data are converted to an array (nodeList) before being displayed in a table:

```
function handleXML (xmlData) {
    var data = xmlData;
    var cd = data.getElementsByTagName("cd");
    var arrayCD = Array.prototype.slice.call(cd);

     var table = "<table>";
     table += "<tbody>";

     for ( var i = 0, len = arrayCD.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            table += "<tr>";
            table += "<td>"+ arrayCD[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ arrayCD[i].getElementsByTagName("artist")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "<td>"+ arrayCD[i].getElementsByTagName("country")[0].firstChild.nodeValue +"</td>";
            table += "</tr>";
        }

        table += "</tbody>";
        table += "</table>";

    return table;
}
```

My question is how to filter the table data so that (for instance) only CDs produced in the UK are displayed.
I've been struggling with this for a while and now begin to feel more and more confused. I suppose a solution could be something like:

```
 arrayCD.filter(function(c) {
        var filterC = c.getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        return (filterC = "UK");
    });
```

(which should be inserted between *var arrayCD* and *var table*). But I simply can't make it work. I'd be glad if somebody could suggest an answer.

Comment: if you want to do it imperatively assign some `data-attr` to each node (td in your table) and set `style=display:none` in your loop. `$('[data-country="blah"]').each(el => $(el).style('display', 'none'))` or something like that, cant remember jquery api anymore

Comment: Thanks, it looks good and it's not the first time that I think that a jQuery answer sounds convincing. Unfortunately, due to company restrictions, the solution I'm looking for has to be XML and Javascript, with no jQuery or JSON.

Comment: json is (usually) native to javascript. jquery is just a fancy wrapper for `document.querySelector` anyway...the strategy is basically the same